# How to delete old desktop background pic?

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

I had set a particular background pic for my 64-bit Windows 10 1903 system, which I now regret. It was easy to change the pic, but the embarrassing image still shows up as one choice when I enter the Background settings.

I've read a lot of postings here and elsewhere giving the paths or methods to find all wallpapers and lock screens and the like, including registry paths containing such paths and powershell scripts to obtain them, but not a one contains the pic in question.

I've also searched for the filename and portions thereof on the entire C drive, but nothing matches. I've even searched for all files of the approximate size (and date, too). Nothing! And the removable drive which held the original image has been removed.

So how does it still show up as one of the choices for background pics? I can even re-establish it as a background!

What other hidy-holes can Windows 10 be using, please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for the image by name in the Registry. Note its location.

- If the file still exists at the location shown, delete it.
- If it no longer exists, delete (or change) the Registry Value containing that string.

Though playing with the Windows Registry *can* make a machine unusable, restricting yourself to that one change should be reasonably safe.

Comment: Thanks! I found the path in unicode below this key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer. My previous searches were made in a third-party Registry tool which defaulted to all ANSI searches, which is why I didn't find it.  I lack the ability to up-vote, but I will try to find a way to indicate you solved my problem.

Comment: Glad it worked!